# File Download plugin for iPhone - Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

How can I download a file from an URL to the **iPhone** file system with Phonegap?! I'm trying to use [this plugin from clearlyinnovative](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2056122828/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url-all-the-code) but it doesn't support the last version of phonegap.
Any ideas?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin from clearlyinnovative does actually support the latest phonegap, with a few changes. You are REALLY close to having this work perfectly.
Recently, phonegap made some changes to their plugin structure. I think these are all of the changes that you will need to make. (assuming you have latest phonegap installed)

PixFileDownload.h:
Change:
    #import "PhoneGapCommand.h"
To:
    #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
Change:
    @interface PixFileDownload : PhoneGapCommand {
To:
    @interface PixFileDownload : PGPlugin {

PixFileDownload.m:
Change:
    -(PhoneGapCommand*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView*)theWebView
To:
    -(PGPlugin*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView*)theWebView

Also, you need to add an entry to the PhoneGap.plist to let the system know about your plugin.
  Add
    *PixFileDownload String PixFileDownload*
to the plist file.

Hope this helps, let me know if you run into any errors, i have the working copy and the old version both in front of me, so I can help.

Comment: This fix doesn't work. There are more lines that need to be edited. Also, the include you specified isn't compatible. it should be: #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>

Answer (score 3):

An up to date version can be found at: https://github.com/halool/PixFileDownload-Plugin
Compiles perfectly with PhoneGap 1.4.1 on XCode 4.2.1